# extract line from file using field values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to extract specific lines from a large file based on a value in the lines. In the follow example file I'd like to extract all lines where the 9th field equals 136 (the 3rd line in this example).

```
1  1  2  0.000000000000000E+00 0.101998342169440E+04  1  1  192  134 0
2  1  2  0.000000000000000E+00 0.925223568652902E+03  1  1  192  135 0
3  1  2  0.000000000000000E+00 0.826768068146788E+03  1  1  192  136 0
4  1  2  0.000000000000000E+00 0.743749759381265E+03  1  1  192  137 0
5  1  2  0.000000000000000E+00 0.674552206394659E+03  1  1  192  138 0
```

I've tried the following code with no success:

```
outfile = open('example_out.txt', 'w')

with open('example_in.txt', 'r') as infile1:
    for line in infile1:
        fields = line.split()
        if fields[8] == 136:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: "with no success" What happened? No output? Wrong output? Exception? Did your computer blow up?

Comment: `fields[8]` is a string and in python `"136" != 136`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` returns a list of strings.  Try `if fields[8] == "136":` instead.

Comment: Or alternatively, `if int(fields[8]) == 136:`

Comment: The problem with that is that it would throw an exception if fields[8] were something other than a number.

Comment: But if it's anything other than a number, than that would probably _be_ an exception, and better not go unnoticed, as with the string comparison.

Comment: I guess it just depends on what you're trying to do.  Sometimes you might want to treat the wrong number differently from a completely different string.